# Commerce Coupon block entry to the review page during order process

Tags: entities, commerce

I just install Commerce Coupon Module 7.x-2.0-rc2 and required dependencies (discount module, inline conditions).
After that I create discount and applied a coupon to it, I also add right permissions to all users (like "Redeem any coupon").
During simulate buying process I see proper field in the form where coupon need to be put, I add coupon with success.
But when want to go the review part of order I can't because I get error "Please enter a code." (but I've already add code and is that code is added). Also
when I don't want to use a coupon code I get the same error. I can't set this form field as "not required". When I go to the
Store -> Configuration -> Order settings ->Manage Fields and want to edit Coupon Field I see text "The field Coupons is locked and cannot be edited."
(I can edit other fields and there is checkbox option "required" ). I'm newbie in drupal and friend of my ask me to add this feature to his existed site (maybe some other modules block or screw coupon module). Drupal version is 7.31

Thanks in advance for help